# How to conditionally fail an Azure Devops Pipeline stage?

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Say I have a pipeline where I invoke a Lambda and it responds 'true'. In this case, the pipeline should proceed. In the other case where the lambda responds 'false', I want to be able to look at that output variable and if it is false, manually fail the deployment stage (so that I can redeploy an old version of the code).

Seems like a simple enough question, but I can't find any info on this simple task.

Comment: Are you having trouble calling the lambda, or handling the result, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a script task as below - exit if lambda output is false

```
- script: |
    lamdaOutput = [result from call]
    if lamdaOutput; then 
       exit 0 
    else 
       exit 1 
    fi
```